# How to encrypt if public key does not have email

Tags: linux, encryption, gpg

How to encrypt a file using the command below, if the recipient mail is not showing up when I type the --list-keys command.

Sample Encrypt file command using GPG

```
gpg --output "output_filename" --encrypt --recipient blake@cyb.org "input_filename"
```

Output for gpg --list-keys shows to imported public keys one is User_A which shows an email. However another one Company ABC doesn't show an email. Which command can I use to encrypt the file and send it to Company ABC where they can decrypt it using their private key?

```
pub   2048R/4XXXX4E4 2016-08-29
uid       [ultimate] User_A <User_A@Test.com>
sub   2048R/DXXXX7E 2016-08-29


pub   1024D/FXXXXX3D 2007-01-20
uid       [ unknown] Company ABC
sub   2048g/7XXXXXE 2007-01-20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the identifier instead of an email address:

```
gpg --output "output_filename" --encrypt --recipient FXXXXX3D "input_filename"
```

(You should really specify the full fingerprint but that's another story.)